# How to search in a folder by the name or extension of a file in winForm in C#?

Tags: c#

First of all we should get a directory by the user. then in the specified folder we want to search a file by its name or its extension. 
for example in that folder we want to search a name "Book" or an extension like .txt .
Suppose that we have a Browse button, and by clicking on it we get the path and show it in a label(in the below code it is label1). and we have a Search button and a textBox that we should write the name or extension in textBox and by clicking on Search button the result(the founded files' names) would be shown in a MessageBox.
i have written a piece of code that only gets the path and i don't know how to write the rest.

```
private void Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        this.label1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        Directory = label1.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're looking for [System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of using [Directory.GetFiles()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) with a search pattern:

```
    private void Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string[] matches = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*book*"); // use "*.txt" to find all text files
            if (matches.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string file in matches)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(file);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No matches found!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose your search button's click event use following function

```
private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo Di=new DirectoryInfo(label1.Text);
    foreach(FileInfo fi in Di.GetFiles())
    {
       textbox.Text+=fi.Name+"\r\n";
    }
}
```